# Trigger on Table A Does Merge (Upsert) into Table B

Tags: t-sql, merge, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to add a trigger to Table A that does an upsert into Table B whenever an insert or update is performed.  I am using a MERGE to accomplish this.

This database is running on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Here is my script:

```
USE [XMPie]
GO

/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[tr_targetupd40836-09]    Script Date: 5/25/2017 10:18:30 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_targetupd40872-01a]
ON [dbo].[40872-01]
after update, insert as

DECLARE @CJ int, @BPID int, @Email varchar(100)

IF (SELECT TOP 1 OptOut FROM inserted) = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT top 1 @CJ = CAST([MicrositeNumber] AS int) FROM inserted

    SELECT TOP 1 @BPID =  bp.BPID
            FROM JandLreporting.dbo.ControlJob cj
            INNER JOIN JandLreporting.dbo.BusinessPartner bp
            ON cj.JLMReferenceID = bp.JLMReferenceID
            WHERE cj.ControlJob = @CJ

    SELECT top 1 @Email = RTRIM(LTRIM(Email)) FROM inserted

    IF @BPID IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [DoNotContactEmail] where Email = @Email and BPID = @BPID)
    INSERT [DoNotContactEmail](email, bpid) VALUES(@Email, @BPID)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    MERGE JandLreporting.dbo.MicrositeResponseAdor AS T  
    USING inserted AS S 
    ON T.RecipientKey = S.RecipientKey
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
         UPDATE set T.[MicrositeResponse_ID]= (s.[MicrositeResponse_ID])
        ,T.[MicrositeNumber]=LEFT(s.[MicrositeNumber],50)
        ,T.[RecipientKey]=LEFT(s.[RecipientKey],101)
        ,T.[Vin]=LEFT(s.[Vin],30)
        ,T.[FirstName]=LEFT(s.[FirstName],50)
        ,T.[MiddleInitial]=LEFT(s.[MiddleInitial],1)
        ,T.[LastName]=LEFT(s.[LastName],50)
        ,T.[FullName]=LEFT(s.[FullName],100)
        ,T.[Address1]=LEFT(s.[Address1],100)
        ,T.[Address2]=LEFT(s.[Address2],50)
        ,T.[City]=LEFT(s.[City],50)
        ,T.[State]=LEFT(s.[State],2)
        ,T.[ZipCode]=LEFT(s.[ZipCode],10)
        ,T.[PhoneNumber]=LEFT(s.[PhoneNumber],15)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
      INSERT (T.[ID]
        ,T.[MicrositeResponse_ID]
        ,T.[MicrositeNumber]
        ,T.[RecipientKey]
        ,T.[Vin]
        ,T.[FirstName]
        ,T.[MiddleInitial]
        ,T.[LastName]
        ,T.[FullName]
        ,T.[Address1]
        ,T.[Address2]
        ,T.[City]
        ,T.[State]
        ,T.[ZipCode]
        ,T.[PhoneNumber]
        )
      VALUES (s.[ID]
        ,s.[MicrositeResponse_ID]
        ,s.[MicrositeNumber]
        ,s.[RecipientKey]
        ,s.[Vin]
        ,s.[FirstName]
        ,s.[MiddleInitial]
        ,s.[LastName]
        ,s.[FullName]
        ,s.[Address1]
        ,s.[Address2]
        ,s.[City]
        ,s.[State]
        ,s.[ZipCode]
        ,s.[PhoneNumber])
END

GO
```

When I try to apply this trigger, I get the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure tr_targetupd40872-01a, Line 26 [Batch Start Line 9]
Incorrect syntax near ' '.
```

I can't figure out where the syntax error is.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Wrap the code in a `BEGIN`/`END` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Where should I put the begin? Before create trigger?

Comment: `insert as begin` and `end` at the end

Comment: Around the body of the `create trigger`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no luck. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the code for the trigger in a `BEGIN`/`END`, as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_targetupd40872-01a]
ON [dbo].[40872-01]
after update, insert as
BEGIN --begin trigger
  DECLARE @CJ int, @BPID int, @Email varchar(100)

  IF (SELECT TOP 1 OptOut FROM inserted) = 1
  BEGIN
    SELECT top 1 @CJ = CAST([MicrositeNumber] AS int) FROM inserted

    SELECT TOP 1 @BPID =  bp.BPID
      FROM JandLreporting.dbo.ControlJob cj
        INNER JOIN JandLreporting.dbo.BusinessPartner bp
          ON cj.JLMReferenceID = bp.JLMReferenceID
      WHERE cj.ControlJob = @CJ

    SELECT top 1 @Email = RTRIM(LTRIM(Email)) FROM inserted

    IF @BPID IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [DoNotContactEmail] where Email = @Email and BPID = @BPID)
    INSERT [DoNotContactEmail](email, bpid) VALUES(@Email, @BPID)
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    MERGE JandLreporting.dbo.MicrositeResponseAdor AS T  
      USING inserted AS S 
      ON T.RecipientKey = S.RecipientKey
      WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
        set T.[MicrositeResponse_ID]= (s.[MicrositeResponse_ID])
           ,T.[MicrositeNumber]=LEFT(s.[MicrositeNumber],50)
           ,T.[RecipientKey]=LEFT(s.[RecipientKey],101)
           ,T.[Vin]=LEFT(s.[Vin],30)
           ,T.[FirstName]=LEFT(s.[FirstName],50)
           ,T.[MiddleInitial]=LEFT(s.[MiddleInitial],1)
           ,T.[LastName]=LEFT(s.[LastName],50)
           ,T.[FullName]=LEFT(s.[FullName],100)
           ,T.[Address1]=LEFT(s.[Address1],100)
           ,T.[Address2]=LEFT(s.[Address2],50)
           ,T.[City]=LEFT(s.[City],50)
           ,T.[State]=LEFT(s.[State],2)
           ,T.[ZipCode]=LEFT(s.[ZipCode],10)
           ,T.[PhoneNumber]=LEFT(s.[PhoneNumber],15)
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
            T.[ID]
           ,T.[MicrositeResponse_ID]
           ,T.[MicrositeNumber]
           ,T.[RecipientKey]
           ,T.[Vin]
           ,T.[FirstName]
           ,T.[MiddleInitial]
           ,T.[LastName]
           ,T.[FullName]
           ,T.[Address1]
           ,T.[Address2]
           ,T.[City]
           ,T.[State]
           ,T.[ZipCode]
           ,T.[PhoneNumber]
        ) VALUES (
           s.[ID]
          ,s.[MicrositeResponse_ID]
          ,s.[MicrositeNumber]
          ,s.[RecipientKey]
          ,s.[Vin]
          ,s.[FirstName]
          ,s.[MiddleInitial]
          ,s.[LastName]
          ,s.[FullName]
          ,s.[Address1]
          ,s.[Address2]
          ,s.[City]
          ,s.[State]
          ,s.[ZipCode]
          ,s.[PhoneNumber]
        )
  END
END  -- End of trigger
GO
```